# Transferring State Between Components - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I have a state in the `App` class, and I want to transfer those values into `SecondApp`, how do you go about that? I've tried using props but when I console log it, I get undefined.

Excuse the nooby question, I'm fairly new and trying to get my hands dirty, haha.

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      todo: ['hello', 'hey']
    }

  }
}

class SecondApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <p>?</p>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you get `undefined`?

Comment: You are right. `props` would be the way to do it.

Comment: @pwolaq when I console it, so I wasn't sure whether it's actually doing something or I'm doing something wrong, lol

Comment: I'm not trying to bash on you, but with the code you posted, it is impossible for anyone to see what you are doing wrong since the code looks far from runnable. You don't seem to be rendering the App component from the code above, nor console.logging anywhere. In a future question, if possible, try to make your issue reproducible on JSFiddle or Codepen, so anyone can look at it and makes changes to make it work. There are very good answers below which should help you. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing the props correctly, they shouldn't turn up undefined. Props would be the correct way to go about this though!

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      todo: ['hello', 'hey']
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <SecondApp testProp={this.state.todo}/>;
  }
}
class SecondApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>this is the prop: {this.props.testProp}</div>;
  }
}
```

If you pass it through like that, you'll see the prop show up as "hellohey", check out the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/106165/). Next off you'll likely want to render these items in a list, and will need to handle that accordingly. [This](http://jasonjl.me/blog/2015/04/18/rendering-list-of-elements-in-react-with-jsx/) article will point you in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to call `SecondApp` in `App` and then pass props.

```js
class SecondApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return ( <
      p > {this.props.todo} < /p>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      todo: ['hello', 'hey']
    }
  }
  render() {
    return ( <
      SecondApp todo = {
        this.state.todo
      } />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to pass data from one app to another (that means, you render an app on an id and another app on another id) you can use events.
Whenever the state of the first app updates, you can dispatch an event and put an event listener on the other app, that updates it's state.
This is a common way to share data between independent modules/apps.
You can read more about this when you google "observer subscriber pattern".

Otherwise, if you mean to pass data to a child component, you really should read the react documentation.